# Why is my Mantis brown?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

One of my Mantis is brown, rather than the usual green. Why?

Comment: This should definitely be a SE meme!

Comment: Brown Mantis hail from the system of Ughathutthuckusa-zathuthuh which was a contender for the seat of the Mantis empire.  It lost not due to a fierce battle, but simply because the Mantis voting on the issue often confused it for Ughathutthucksa-zathutthuh, which is, of course, the Mantis term for "suprisingly clean restroom."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its new racial coloring introduced in the latest update.  Races now can have alternative colors.  Their stats remain the same no matter the color.

Comment: Engi do not have different colors.  But they are the exception.

Comment: And you can now have black human crew! Diversity! \o/